# how to check when a user has input in python

Tags: python, user-input, calculator

I'm trying make a calculator in python so i need this mechanism,when user enters a number i show it and i want it to be saved and then when he clicks for example plus sign then the screen should turn blank again and he enters other number and when he clicks equal it is added.

PS: please only check the badd() and beql() function that has the problem,Why the function bc() not getting called?

My code:

```
    from Tkinter import*



#function for about menu 
def about():
    win2=Tk()
    win2.wm_title("About")
    l=Label(win2,text=" CAL-C ver 1.0 \n Developer. \n Mohd Sanad",padx=5,pady=40)
    l.pack()
st=""
def but1():
    global st
    st=st+"1"
    v.set(st)
def but2():
    global st
    st=st+"2"
    v.set(st)
def but3():
    global st
    st=st+"3"
    v.set(st)
def but4():
    global st
    st=st+"4"
    v.set(st)
def but5():
    global st
    st=st+"5"
    v.set(st)
def but6():
    global st
    st=st+"6"
    v.set(st)
def but7():
    global st
    st=st+"7"
    v.set(st)
def but8():
    global st
    st=st+"8"
    v.set(st)
def but9():
    global st
    st=st+"9"
    v.set(st)
def but10():
    global st
    st=st+"0"
    v.set(st)
def bc():
    global st
    v.set("")
    st=""
def beql(x):
        bc()
        v.set(str(x))
def badd():
        x=int(st)
        bc()
        y=int(v.get())
        sum=x+y
        beql(sum)




win=Tk()#creating window
win.title("Calculator")#changing window title
win.config(background= "white")
#Initiliazing about menu button
menubar=Menu(win,bg="brown")
menubar.add_command(label="About",command=about)
win.config(menu=menubar)


#TextField
v=StringVar()
e=Entry(win,textvariable=v)
e.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,sticky=W+E)
#Initializing buttons
b1=Button(win,text="1",bg="red")
b2=Button(win,text="2",bg="red")
b3=Button(win,text="3",bg="red")
b4=Button(win,text="4",bg="red")
b5=Button(win,text="5",bg="red")
b6=Button(win,text="6",bg="red")
b7=Button(win,text="7",bg="red")
b8=Button(win,text="8",bg="red")
b9=Button(win,text="9",bg="red")
b10=Button(win,text="0",bg="red")
bdec=Button(win,text=".",bg="orange")
badd=Button(win,text="+",bg="yellow")
bsub=Button(win,text="-",bg="yellow")
bmul=Button(win,text="x",bg="yellow")
bdiv=Button(win,text="/",bg="yellow")
bclear=Button(win,text="CS",bg="blue")
beql=Button(win,text="=",bg="orange")
#Positioning Buttons

b1.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W+E)
b2.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W+E)
b3.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=W+E)
b4.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W+E)
b5.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W+E)
b6.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky=W+E)
b7.grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W+E)
b8.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W+E)
b9.grid(row=3,column=2,sticky=W+E)
b10.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky=W+E)
bdec.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=W+E)
badd.grid(row=1,column=3,sticky=W+E)
bsub.grid(row=2,column=3,sticky=W+E)
bmul.grid(row=3,column=3,sticky=W+E)
bdiv.grid(row=4,column=3,sticky=W+E)
bclear.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky=W+E)
beql.grid(row=4,column=2,sticky=W+E)
#configuring button behaviour
b1.config(command=but1)
b2.config(command=but2)
b3.config(command=but3)
b4.config(command=but4)
b5.config(command=but5)
b6.config(command=but6)
b7.config(command=but7)
b8.config(command=but8)
b9.config(command=but9)
b10.config(command=but10)
bclear.config(command=bc)
beql.config(command=beql)
badd.config(command=badd)
```

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? Also, is that indentation in the second block how it is in the code or a copy-paste error?

Comment: no error the second piece of code is not working at all and im not getting the desired output ,its copy -paste error

Comment: please re check my question thanks :)

Comment: What are `st`, `x`, `v`, etc.? Please post a complete example.

Comment: Brendan Long please now see it

Comment: @MohdSanadZakiRizvi You are aware that using `st` in this way will make it so that the last button will have `123456789...` on it, right?

Comment: yes that's what we want in a calculator if you are inputting a 10 digit number it should be like this ?

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1413, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/sanad/CALCgui.py", line 62, in badd1
    y=int(v.get())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting your `badd` and `beql` functions when you define the buttons to have the same names.

```
...

def beql(x):
    bc()
    v.set(str(x))
def badd():
    x=int(st)
    bc()
    y=int(v.get())
    sum=x+y
    beql(sum)

# beql and badd are now functions

...

badd=Button(win,text="+",bg="yellow")
beql=Button(win,text="=",bg="orange")
# beql and badd are now Button instances

beql.config(command=beql)
badd.config(command=badd)
# configure the button to call the Button instance when pressed.
```